# MySQL failed connection attempts hitting max_connections

Tags: mysql, limits

I run a couple of websites but I believe one of them is causing too many `Connections Failed Attempts` that causes `max_connections` variable to hit.

Currently, `max_connections=2500` (already large) but total connections per hour due to failed attempts have become greater than 3000. How do I debug this? The `httpd error log` for the website does show a couple of PHP warnings/notices though. For example, using `mysqli` instead in the database config.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/multiple-connections-on-mysql-database-with-no-users-on-httpd?rq=1)?

Comment: You need to check your code that opens DB connections.  Number of failed connections is just a counter, I wouldn't worry too much about it but its high number suggests something is not right in the code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the failed connections are causing the max connections issue, but can you set log_warnings=2 and after a short time, view the error log to see if there is more information there? The error log would record something like "access denied for user 'user'@'host'..."

The command to set log_warnings=2 is:

```
set global log_warnings=2;
```

You can find the error log like this:

```
show global variables like 'log_error';
```

What version of mysql are you running?

Can you also show the output of:

```
show global variables like 'skip_name_resolve';
```

and:

```
show global status like 'max_used_connections';
```

Answer (score 1):

Decrease the maximum number of connections to your web server.  20 is probably a realistic number.  For Apache, this is MaxClients.

Do not, without a good reason, have more than one connection to MySQL from each PHP script.

Your screen shot shows only 111 as "max concurrent conections".  (Presumably this comes from `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections';`)  So, `max_connections` is much too high.  I rarely see a need for more than 1000.  In your case, there is evidence that 111 is high enough.

Since it is dangerous (for RAM usage) to set `max_connections` too high, I suggest you decrease it to 200.

"Failed attempts" sounds a bit like the `STATUS` `Aborted_connects`.  For that, 453/hour is moderately high, but I don't see it as a red flag.  It could be that some hacker has tried to get in.  Is port 3306 exposed outside your machine/LAN?

If you would like further analysis, please provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` and `SHOW VARIABLES;`, plus how much RAM.  (Probably need a postit-like site.)